# How do i disable security for OPTIONS method using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a REST services implemented with custom filter, i would like to disable security for all the requests coming with method OPTIONS. I tried to find the information on the web, but could not fine. Any points would be helpful.

I have the same intercept-url for both, only OPTIONS method requests should be disabled for security. One of the option which is tried:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="CSSCustomAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    pattern="/**" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
    create-session="stateless">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"
        method="OPTIONS" requires-channel="any" />

    <security:custom-filter ref="userAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
        position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />

</security:http>
```

Comment: Authentication works including OPTIONS request. I would like to disable the Authentication for OPTIONS request.

Comment: what I think is the order of your intercept-url access="isAuthenticated()" should define first before access="permitAll"?

Comment: did not help as all requests goes with first interceptor